# PHP: Run through multiple URLs and display their content

Tags: php

Let's say we have an URL looking something like this.

http://domain.com/index.php?p=1&u=A1b2C3d4E5f6G7h8I9j

The number span after ?p= goes from 1 to 999 and the rest is unchanged.

Every URL contains one short line of text.

What would a script look like which can run through all 999 URLs and display their contents?

Comment: were and how is the content being stored?

Comment: what do you mean ? no matter what p is you run through all ??

Comment: How about a for loop going from 1 to 999, and then using `file_get_contents` for each one? Note that depending on the response time of a single request, this could take a while.

Comment: maybe as simple as: `for($i = 1; $i < 1000; $i++) {$line = file_get_contents(sprintf('http://domain.com/index.php?p=%d&u=A1b2C3d4E5f6G7h8I9j ', $i));}` ? of course, file_get_contents should be allowed to fetch remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easy. You can use the `FOR LOOP`.

```
<?php
for($i=1; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    echo file_get_contents('http://domain.com/index.php?p=' . $i . '&u=A1b2C3d4E5f6G7h8I9j');
}
```

Documentations:

[For Loop](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.for.php)

[file_get_contents() method](http://php.net/file_get_contents)

Answer (score -1):

This is going to be resource intensive. But taking a shot in the dark, this should work:

```
<?php
   $urlContent = array();
   $urlStart = 'http://domain.com/index.php?p=';
   $urlEnd = '&u=A1b2C3d4E5f6G7h8I9j';
   $count = 1;
   while($count <= 999){
      $urlContent[$count] = file_get_contents($urlStart.$count.$urlEnd);
      $count++;
   }
   foreach($urlContent as $content){
     echo $content.'\n';
   }
?>
```

This code is Untested

Comment: This code is very bulky. This task can be done in just 3 lines, with the use of a for loop.

Comment: I take into account the fact that he has ommited how he wants to display the content, and where as well. My code allows him to place the content anywhere, where yours my good sir, just dumps it on the page.

Comment: well, even my code could be placed anywhere. Perhaps in a `<div>` or wherever he wishes, all he has to do is place it in there.